# Is Debian 9.5 stretch vulnerable to CVE-2018-17182?

Tags: linux, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities, kernel

I have a Debian system running the following kernel version:

`Linux REDACTED 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux Linux REDACTED 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`Distributor ID:    Debian Description: Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch) Release: 9.5 Codename:   stretch Codename:   stretch`

Is this kernel vulnerable to `CVE-2018-17182`?

This is my reference:

https://www.securityweek.com/google-project-zero-discloses-new-linux-kernel-flaw

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2018-17182

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All mainline kernels from 3.15-rc8 commit  [6b4ebc3a9078c5b7b8c4cf495a0b1d2d0e0bfe7a](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6b4ebc3a9078c5b7b8c4cf495a0b1d2d0e0bfe7a), up to the patch in 4.19-rc3 commit [7a9cdebdcc17e426fb5287e4a82db1dfe86339b2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7a9cdebdcc17e426fb5287e4a82db1dfe86339b2) are affected, and the Debian team has not patched it downstream for the version you are using.

Comment: Note that kernels which default to `kernel.panic_on_oops=1` are not affected.

Comment: @forest Source? Won't that just make the kernel panic after the bug is triggered? I wouldn't call that "not affected" if that's the case.

Comment: It will make the kernel panic _when_ the bug is triggered. Setting that sysctl (or setting it as a boot parameter) turns a privesc bug into a DoS bug.

Comment: How to know default `kernel.panic_on_oops` value for my kernel?